# Limiting the number of watches created while using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am creating a standard table using angular's ng-repeat directive. My table will be carrying 10000 cells. As far as I understand, ng-repeat creates watches on every cell and this can significantly erode the performance of my app. Any clues on how I can restrict the number of watches while ensuring that data binding functions the way it shoul.

I have a plnkr here. The template for table is in the file layout.html

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hahh4uyQ130zOS8noC3D

Comment: Use this: https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce

Comment: bindonce works really well, using it in production